# Disable Upgrade-Insecure-Requests in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, https, http-headers

I run a PHP+Apache2 application locally - for development purposes.

The app is running at http://x.dev (a virtual host + an entry in hosts file)

After Firefox updated it seems that I can no longer access http://x.dev as the address in address bar is changed, by the browser, in https://x.dev which obviously is not configured.

I used older version of Firefox (49) vs the new one (59.0.2) and the difference seems to be a new header "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" that was added to the request.

This seems to force http to https, thus causing an issue.

Bellow is what I got after I try to access http://x.dev :

[image]

I saw the same behavior in Chrome. Edge seems to not be "plagued" by this one.

AFAIK this new header was added to improve security (I'm fine with that), but is there any method (configure Firefox) to get back to old behavior (not sending this value)? Or any change on server side to ignore that request?

Comment: Not at all a duplicate of that question. The other one is about Chrome. Also if you read it it's specifically about .dev domains which is totally unrelated to this question. This question is still unanswered.